# a math-software that can compute analytic spread

Tags: commutative-algebra, math-software, analytic-spread

> I want to compute "analytic spread" . So I need a math-software that can compute it.

can anyone help please?

Here is the definition:

[image: def. 4.6.7]

Comment: Also [asked at MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/190935/15503).

Answer (score 1):

Karl  Schwede answered this question [here](//mathoverflow.net/questions/190935/intuitive-interpretation-of-analytic-spread), as: **Question 2: Computing it**